# Android 4.3 crop gallery resultCode Cancel

Tags: android, gallery, crop

My Galaxy Nexus is now running on Android 4.3 allowing me to test my application with this new version. Everything seems fine except cropping.

I have an application that uses the camera to take picture and then crop the image through the gallery app.

I am also able to choose a picture from the gallery and crop it after.
Since Android 4.3, the gallery application changed.

If i take a picture with the camera api and then ask the gallery to crop it in my **onActivityResult method the resultCode is set to 0** (meaning cancel) whereas i clicked on "Save" from the crop view.

But if i choose a picture from the gallery and crop it everything works, the resultCode parameter is set to -1.
I call the same method to crop the picture in both cases.

I have quickpic (an alternative to the gallery app) on my phone, with it everything works !

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {
        int aspectX = 750;
        int aspectY = 1011;

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("scale", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
        intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));

        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine on Android 4.2.2.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered just using a library like this one:

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

I find the com.android.camera.action.CROP can sometimes behave differently from phone to phone and is not always available, so it could cause some problems for you anyway if you are looking to release it.

**UPDATE:**

I have tested the above library with Android 4.3 and it works with no problem. You just need to add the library to your project.

You can then write your method in a very similar way:

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
//you have to convert picUri to string and remove the "file://" to work as a path for this library
String path = picUri.toString().replaceAll("file://", "");

try {
    int aspectX = 750;
    int aspectY = 1011;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
    //send the path to CropImage intent to get the photo you have just taken or selected from gallery
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, path);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));

    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Thx works great. But can you explain this behaviour on Android 4.3? I have seen this wierd behaviour also on Android 4.1 on the Samsung s3 devices.

Comment: @noxius do you mean the behaviour of the android    com.android.camera.action.CROP ? or do you mean the behaviour of the library I suggested?

Comment: the behaviour of android that it returns 0 = cancel after taking a picture

Comment: Ah, Well as for Samsung, I think most of their phones use the TW (TouchWiz) Camera app for their camera and com.android.camera.action.CROP is only a part of the AOSP (Android Open Source Project) camera app, therefore its not supported on most Samsung phones. I think in 4.3 they have updated the AOSP Camera app so now the crop behaves differently, however I have not looked in to the Android source code to find out exactly what has changed. But based on the Samsung issue, its best to avoid the Android crop and use a library to reduce compatibility issues on other devices too. Hope that helped.

Comment: I've tested com.android.camera.action.CROP on Most Samsung devices (Note2, note 1, GS3, GS4, GS2) It works well. Also, on Nexus Devices with 4.3. It's just providing proper extra options. The Crop intent is found in source code for all of them.

Comment: I would say its best not to use the AOSP crop if you are planning on releasing..you never know where its going to fall down if an earlier/later device does not support it. I would avoid relying on it and create your own crop or use a library this way you know it will always be part of your application rather than the device source code.

Answer (score 3):

Above library is only useful if your cropping into a lot smaller images. If you want to crop to a better resolution images, it is best to use the Android Crop Intent.

picUri must be a valid URI which points to your image and outputUri should be a new file you created for writing the cropped image. It works on all devices and 4.3 Source code does indeed have com.android.camera.action.CROP intent available for usage. I've tested this on many devices and it works well.

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri, Uri outputUri) {
    try {
        int aspectX = 2000;
    int aspectY = 1200;

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("scale", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
        intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", false);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem on a Nexus 10 as well. the crop intent returns a cancelled code. after some tweaking I've found a solution:

In my case the input file set in `setDataAndType()` was the same file as the output set using the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra. Using the same file for input and output worked fine on most devices, specifically on devices below 4.3. However on 4.3 it would result in canceled crops. Simply using different files for input and output resolved the issue.

So what you need to make sure of is that your `picUri` parameter points to a file that is not the same as your `mCurrentPhotoPath`. I'm not sure what exactly changed from 4.2 to 4.3 to cause this issue. But using different files seems to resolve it easily.