# Is com.android.camera.action.CROP not available for Android jelly bean 4.3?

Tags: android, camera

I was using com.android.camera.action.CROP for cropping after taking pic using camera.

Below was my code which used to work earlier before 4.3.

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                        cropIntent.setType("image/*");
                        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", Conf.getInt("IMAGE_WIDTH"));
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", Conf.getInt("IMAGE_HEIGHT"));
                        cropIntent.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But now since android crop action takes you to gallery(because gallery is default with crop), this cropping method fails(photo is not saved to gallery).

Does any one knows a way out of this issue. Where I can use the crop on the photo taken from camera

Comment: Include this library: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

Comment: For the crop method - you can take a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930577/android-4-3-crop-gallery-resultcode-cancel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copying the answer from a similar question asked earlier..

Have you considered just using a library like this one:

[GitHubLink](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)

I find the com.android.camera.action.CROP can sometimes behave differently from phone to phone and is not always available, so it could cause some problems for you anyway if you are looking to release it.

> UPDATE:

I have tested the above library with Android 4.3 and it works with no problem. You just need to add the library to your project.

You can then write your method in a very similar way:

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
//you have to convert picUri to string and remove the "file://" to work as a path for this library
String path = picUri.toString().replaceAll("file://", "");
try {
    int aspectX = 750;
    int aspectY = 1011;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
    //send the path to CropImage intent to get the photo you have just taken or selected from gallery
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, path);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));

    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: How do you add the project as a library in Android Studio?

Comment: The libary only allows you to use set memory for apps therefore you will not be able to crop a large resolution image. You can still use the standard android intent on 4.3 shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19435016/1499064

Comment: @JohnBale you have to create a libs folder under main directory and then add it into your build.gradle file

Comment: It suggests the path where you want your cropped photo to be..you can give the current photo path only to replace it with the cropped one..

Comment: Did you actually see the behavior "I find the com.android.camera.action.CROP can sometimes behave differently from phone to phone". I wish to know what deviation did you notice?

Answer (score 1):

According to [@commonsware 's post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) 
This intent is based on `AOSP camera app` which may or may not be available in target device, for some 4.3 devices it may work while for some it wil not.
 
So better approach will be to use any open source library found [at Android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45)
(make sure they are also not based on `AOSP`).

Comment: does anyone have any proof that it doesn't work on "some devices?" Also, which devices are we talking about here? Samsung, HTC?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple of croppers. Especially the ones as referred by [commonsware](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) are not maintained very well. For example pictures taken with rotation data in the meta info are not well rotated. I've found this one: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3487 and its great. Note: make sure you add the activity with an actionbar theme!