# Impossible to crop image from Photos

Tags: java, android

I want to pick an image in the app "Photos" of Google+.
Then, I crop this image with the crop of Google plus too.
But when I valid my crop, a toast appears with the text "Impossible de to save modifications" and the blue circle does not stop.
Why ?

Code :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setData(selectedimg);
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 170);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 170);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem. I haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of Android vendors whose devices do not support this action. Have a look at the the following links. 
http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

[Is com.android.camera.action.CROP not available for Android jelly bean 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013406/is-com-android-camera-action-crop-not-available-for-android-jelly-bean-4-3)

http://androidthings.blogspot.gr/2012/08/using-android-crop-intent-and-action.html#.U0J27vl_uDo

Comment: The thing is, Google+ Photos App supports Crop. In fact, if you launch and ACTION_PICK intent with intent.putExtra("crop", "true"); and then select Gallery, and then when you pick the picture, choose Photos App to crop, that works. The problem is when you choose Photos to pick the picture, because then the crop is never trigered. So I my guess is that PhotosApp has a different crop parameter that the intent should provide

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. When you select the Google+ Photos app to select the image, the crop is never triggered. On the other hand if you choose the gallery to select the image then you can crop it with the Google+ Photos app.