# How to get Crop Package Name using by android device

Tags: android, android-intent

`Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP", null);`
Package: "com.android.camera.action" is not available in all the android devices(like Nexus 7).Is there any code to get the name of "crop package" used by that android device.

Answer (score 0):

have you check this
[Android 4.3 crop gallery resultCode Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930577/android-4-3-crop-gallery-resultcode-cancel/17936142#17936142)

Have you considered just using a library like this one:

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

I find the com.android.camera.action.CROP can sometimes behave differently from phone to phone and is not always available, so it could cause some problems for you anyway if you are looking to release it.

**UPDATE:**

I have tested the above library with Android 4.3 and it works with no problem. You just need to add the library to your project.

You can then write your method in a very similar way:

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
//you have to convert picUri to string and remove the "file://" to work as a path for this library
String path = picUri.toString().replaceAll("file://", "");

try {
    int aspectX = 750;
    int aspectY = 1011;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
    //send the path to CropImage intent to get the photo you have just taken or selected from gallery
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, path);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));

    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Yes.I am working on the library that you had mentioned.But I want to know how to get the name of package used by android devices.It's better to implement "default crop function" used by android device.

Comment: I am not sure, if there is a way to find the specific class package based on what action they perform.

But by using "ACTION_VIEW" on image URI or specifying type with "image/*" will list out all the options through which can be opened or manipulated.

Comment: you can even set an option of crop the image while selecting image either form gallery or capture from camera, without calling intent other time for "crop"

Comment: But I also want to rotate the image while cropping.That's why I am not using crop with camera and gallery.