# Want Open exactly the Gallery in Android

Tags: android, gallery

I want to open the default Gallery in Android device, but when I used the following code it opens "Photos" if user preference that.

Code I used,

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
in.putExtra("crop", "true");
startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: ya i also have problem like that how to avoid a image from cloud to be attached to the application...

Answer (score 4):

You should have to use this code.

by this you can switch to Gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

***I think [setPackage(String packageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29) do your task.***

---

Example

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
in.putExtra("crop", "true");
in.setPackage(PACKAGE_NAME_OF_GALLERY); // Make sure if it is com.android.gallery3d
startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Crashed,
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/images/media pkg=com.android.gallery3d (has extras) }

Comment: You need to identify how can you pass image to the application gallery to crop.. Other look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930577/android-4-3-crop-gallery-resultcode-cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a similar way I used below. You have to set `Class Name` manually. This will probably won't work on older devices and future devices. The class name will definitely change.

I think they will get rid of Gallery application and just use Photos at some point.

```
in.setClassName("com.android.gallery3d", "com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery");
if(isAvailable(context, in)) {
    //Open it. 
}
else {
    //Do it the old way
}
```

And the `isAvailable` function is

```
public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    if(ctx == null)
        return false;
   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> list =
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
         PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media")); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to pick, it doesn't work for ACTION_PICK. As we can't get the path

Comment: This code open exactly the complete gallery including photos and videos, I tested it. What exactly you looking for? Please elaborate.

Comment: I was not able to crop it when it selected from Photos